# camel HTTP4 JBoss : unable to find valid certification path to requested target

Tags: jboss, jbossfuse, camel-http

I request a access token from a UAA service. recieve the token. then use the token to upload a file to an AWS environment. now it works with one environment and doesn't work with another.  the only major difference can find is that the one that works uses SSO auth and and one that doesn't work uses UAA auth.  since I request a token from a UAA server/service and use it to POST a data file to an environment I don't have use of a key store.  I am getting the following error.

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

I am using JBoss Fuse JBoss Fuse (6.3.0.redhat-310) container running my application bundles

Java 8
Camel-HTTP4 to post

any suggestions or help would be greatly appreciated, is there anything I am missing? does anything special need to be done ?  thank you!

oh yeah, It works when I do it in Postman? not in fuse?
it also works with Curl.

```
HTTP/1.1 200 Connection Established
Proxy-Agent: Zscaler/6.0

HTTP/1.1 100 Continue
Server: Zscaler/6.0

HTTP/1.1 201 Created
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Content-Length: 0
Corr: ef75916afaf1db34
Date: Tue, 05 Jun 2018 22:58:27 GMT
Expires: 0
Pragma: no-cache
Server: none
X-Application-Context: APMTS:cloud:10
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: DENY
X-Vcap-Request-Id: 1b964238-0dbc-4c09-7c6f-0bc429698584
X-Xss-Protection: 1; mode=block
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found my problem was with certs. I located the certs for those systems, imported to java keystore. problem is gone.

thank you all